# Why settle for Lagrange Interpolation when doing linear multistep ODE integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation

Say that we have some initial value problem:

$y'(t) = f(t,y(t)) ; y(0) = y_0$

with $y_0$ and $f(t,y(t))$ known.

If we use Euler's method to numerically approximate the first k points, then we have $y_0, y_1,...y_k$ (our approximations) known.

The other day, my professor derived the Adams-Bashforth method to get an estimate for $y_{k+1}$:

$\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}y'(t)dt = \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} f(t,y(t))dt$

$y(t_{k+1}) - y(t_k) = \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} f(t,y(t))dt$

$y(t_{k+1}) = y(t_k) + \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} f(t,y(t))dt$

Since we have $y_k$ as an estimate for $y(t_k)$, all we need to estimate is the integral. My professor suggests using the Lagrange interpolating polynomial passing through these k+1 points and then integrating that polynomial to get an approximation for the interval, yielding the Adams-Bashforth method. This makes sense.

My question is, since we have information about the derivatives (that is, y'(t) is known) at each point, why don't we use Hermite interpolation (or otherwise put that information to work somehow)? Wouldn't that be more accurate than Lagrange? My professor didn't know, and after a little (well, admittedly, very little) digging, I haven't found a name for that method.

If that method exists, I would love to hear its name. If not, I would love to hear why it isn't used (maybe it's unstable/expensive/inconsistent?).

Comment: I don't know the answer here so I can only speculate. I see no reason one cannot use Hermite, the big question is if it's worth it. First off all it's more of an effort to implement it in codes (more coding) but more importantly it requires twice as many function-evaluations to compute the Hermite interpolating polynomial IIRC making it more time-consuming. Thus we can probably run with Lagrange and use more steps to "beat" the gain in accuracy when using Hermite. With all numerics one has to hedge accuracy versus computation time (and effort in imlementing it).

Comment: Raising the degree of polynomial interpolants becomes very bad very quickly when doing numerics, because of stability issues related to the Runge phenomenon. Indeed there is a famous theorem (though I forget the name) which says that a linear multistep method which is stable can only have some maximum order (I think 2).

Comment: @Ian That is a very good point; btw I found the theorem (I think) you are referring to in one of my books, it's seems to be called the "Dahlquist Barrier". And the maximum order for guaranteed stability is indeed $k=2$ ("For an a-stable multistep-method to be stable we need the order to satisfy $k\leq 2$.").

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's been a few years since I studied this material so I had forgotten.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Looks like this might have something do with the answer. Though I wonder if we could use fewer points + their derivatives, as in if we were going to do k steps, do k/2 steps and use Hermite.